# What's polluting the global namespace here?

Tags: c++, namespaces, libc++

This code compiles on recent gcc and clang:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   std::vector<int> v(20);
   fill(begin(v), end(v), 0);
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But surely it SHOULD NOT.

Don't I need `std::fill(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 0);`?

What's changed? Why are these functions in the global namespace?

Comment: Headers are allowed to include other headers. You just can't rely on it.

Comment: Nothing changed. ADL is pretty old. Though you'd probably get the error you expect if you build with optimizations.

Comment: It all makes perfect sense now. Never bothered to learn what ADL was, other than how to use std::swap properly. Kinda wish it wasn't a language feature, or it worked differently. Definitely see the potential for head scratching bugs.